# $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Using Fourier series I have managed to show that

$$ \frac{x^4}{12} = \frac{\pi^2 x^2}{6} + 4 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}(1-\cos(nx)) , x \in [-\pi,\pi]$$

From here apparently one need just one step to find an expression for $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$. I need a hint what this step might be.

Comment: @Joanpemo just a type, fixed it.

Comment: Without even thinking I'd say you just have to pick an appropriate value of $x$. Have you tried this?

Comment: @GitGud yep, also without thinking tried to shoot $x = \pi, x = \pi/2$ at it, but without any result.

Comment: Setting $x=\pi$ looks good to me, But I didn't follow through. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @GitGud Because you only get the odd terms of the series that way. But probably it can be combined with another clever choice of $x$ to give the result.

Comment: @BenS. yeh, that also was my guess, what is left is to find this clever choice ;)

Comment: @BenS. I just realised, thanks. Good idea.

Comment: Are you sure that you've shown the right equation? In the factor $1-\cos(nx)$, where is the $1-$ coming from?

Comment: @BrentKerby you integrate two times $x^2 = \pi^2 / 3 + 4 \sum [(-1)^n / n^2] \cos(nx)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $\;x=\pi\;$:

$$\frac{\pi^4}{12}=\frac{\pi^4}6+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}\left(1-(-1)^n\right)\stackrel{\text{Only odd index matters}}\implies\frac{\pi^4}{96}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^4}$$

and from here:

$$I:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\frac1{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^4}=\frac1{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}+\frac{\pi^4}{96}\implies$$

$$\color{red}{I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{96}\cdot\frac{16}{15}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}}$$

Comment: Well done!   +1...