# From $\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi^2 n^2}\cos(2\pi nx)=(1-2x)^2$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I'm working on a proof of the following:

"Let $f(x)$ be the function defined by $f(x)=(1-2x)^2$ when $x\in [0,1)$ and extended to be $\mathbb{Z}$-periodic for the rest of the real line.

(a) Show that the series $\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi^2 n^2}\cos(2\pi nx)$ converges uniformly to $f$;

(b) Conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$;

(c) Conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$."

Now, I managed to prove $(a)$ and $(b)$ but I'm stuck on $(c)$ so I'd appreciate any hint about how to finish this last step.

(Note: I know there are other questions on this topic but they use different series, so this is not a duplicate)

Comment: (c) follows from Parseval's identity.

Comment: The initial formula is wrong. --- You can get (c) without special theorems by double integration.

Comment: Well, please include your work on (a), (b)$.  This is a multipart question, in which you can expect to base your conclusion on (c), on the work you did on (a) (b), which you need to show us, so we can gauge whether you're on the right track, or if you failed on (a), (b).   (Note: when you claim in a question that you've done x, y, and z, then show us your workings on x, y, and z.)

Comment: (c) is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1775879/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(c)  $\enspace\displaystyle  \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi^2n^2}\cos(2\pi nx) = (2x-1)^2-\frac{1}{3} $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_0^x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^2n^2}\cos(2\pi nt)dt = \int\limits_0^x ((t-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{12})dt $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^3n^3}\sin(2\pi nx) = 2\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^3}{3}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{x}{6} $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_0^x\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^3n^3}\sin(2\pi nt) dt = \int\limits_0^x (2\frac{(t-\frac{1}{2})^3}{3}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{t}{6} )dt $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^4n^4}(1-\cos(2\pi nx)) = \frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^4}{3}-\frac{1}{48}+\frac{x}{6}-\frac{x^2}{6}  $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^4n^4}(1-(-1)^n) = \frac{1}{48} $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{96} $

=>  $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^4}}\frac{\pi^4}{96} = \frac{\pi^4}{90} $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** use [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) to relate the series of the squared coefficients to $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx$.